# Quotation marks in an escaped sequence of a lstlisting don't appear properly

Tags: listings

I'm trying to make some parts in HTML code in a lstlisting coloured by using \textcolor in an escaped sequence. I've used this technique in another code snippet where everything worked out fine. For some reason the only time when I don't get an error while compiling is when I use german quotation marks, but they don't show up properly. The code as condensed example is basically this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,frame=leftline,escapechar=@}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML]
...
<input type="text" @\textcolor{Green}{id="`hex"'}@ /> 
... 
<input type="text" @\textcolor{Green}{id="`string"'}@ />
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

It comes up like this:

[image]

So what I need to know is why does this happen, what can I do about it and can I possibly get it to work with english quotation marks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may change the current language via the new command `\entextcolor` (using `\foreignlanguage` from `babel`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,frame=leftline,escapechar=@}

\newcommand\entextcolor[2]{\foreignlanguage{english}{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML]
...
<input type="text" @\entextcolor{Green}{id="`hex"'}@ /> 
... 
<input type="text" @\entextcolor{Green}{id="`string"'}@ />
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, works fine! Still very new to LaTeX so there's a lot to learn